# extract API responses for multiple accounts

Tags: api, python-2.7, pandas, interactive-brokers, ibpy

I am new to IBPy and really interested to know how to get account parameters for multiple accounts. The code below only gives me the output in the command line but I couldn't figure out how to store those information into a dataframe. the function updateAccountValue() doesn't have a unique id that i can use as index for the dataframe.

```
from ib.opt import Connection, message
import pandas as pd
import time

def error_handler(msg):
    """Handles the capturing of error messages"""
    print "Server Error: %s" % msg

def updateAccount_handler(msg):
    if msg.key in ['AccountType','NetLiquidation']:
        print msg.key, msg.value

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conn = Connection.create(port=7497, clientId = 93)
    conn.connect()

    conn.register(error_handler, 'Error')
    conn.register(updateAccount_handler,message.updateAccountValue)

    # we can do a loop, i am just giving a simple example for 2 accounts
    conn.reqAccountUpdates(1,"Uxxxx008")
    time.sleep(0.5)

    conn.reqAccountUpdates(1,"Uxxxx765")
    time.sleep(0.5)

    conn.disconnect()
```

the output looks like this:

```
Server Version: 76
TWS Time at connection:20150729 12:46:56 EST
Server Error: <error id=-1, errorCode=2104, errorMsg=Market data farm connection is OK:usfuture>
Server Error: <error id=-1, errorCode=2104, errorMsg=Market data farm connection is OK:usfuture.us>
Server Error: <error id=-1, errorCode=2104, errorMsg=Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm>
Server Error: <error id=-1, errorCode=2106, errorMsg=HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds>
AccountType INDIVIDUAL
NetLiquidation 2625.24
AccountType IRA-ROTH NEW
NetLiquidation 11313.83
```

End goal is to store these information into a pandas dataframe format with an unique id of account number.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, The IBpy works in sender/Receiver architecture. What I would like suggest you is to have a global variable to store the account information.

```
from ib.opt import Connection, message
import pandas as pd
import time
class account_update :
   acc_info = [] # list to store all your account info
   # you can have list,tuple,panda dataframe or any data strucure I am using normal list to demonstrate
   def error_handler(self,msg):
       """Handles the capturing of error messages"""
       print "Server Error: %s" % msg

   def updateAccount_handler(self,msg):
       if msg.key in ['AccountType','NetLiquidation']:
           self.acc_info.append(msg.key, msg.value)

   def main(self):
       conn = Connection.create(port=7497, clientId = 93)
       conn.connect()

       conn.register(error_handler, 'Error')
       conn.register(updateAccount_handler,message.updateAccountValue)

       conn.reqAccountUpdates(1,"Uxxxx008")
       time.sleep(0.5)

       conn.reqAccountUpdates(1,"Uxxxx765")
       time.sleep(0.5)

       conn.disconnect()

if __name__ == "__main__" :
     account_update().main()
```

So the logic is simple,create a global variable and make your response handler method to update the global variable whenever it receives a response. Hope it works :)